# Force Google Translate to translate <code>

Tags: html, google-translate

Is it possible to force Google Translate to translate `<code>` tags on a website?

For example I have the following sentence:

```html
Changed status from <code>processing</code> to <code>shipped</code>.
```

But Google Translate is leaving code blocks untranslated which is understandable, but in this case I'd want them to be translated.

### Background:

We're using `ngx-md` which is a markdown library for Angular which inserts `<code>` around backticks and we've got tons of strings saved like that in the database so replacing that isn't preferrable.

Comment: When I insert "Hello <code>world</code>" into Google translate, I get the result "你好<code>世界</code>". Otherwise, couldn't you just replace `<code>` and `</code>` by something else or remove entirely?

Comment: @Green We're using the Google Translate widget on a website, not pasting it into Google Translate. We could potentially replace all occurrences of <code> on the website, but as I mentioned they are generated by the markdown library but it's not very straight forward to do so and thus not a preferable solution.